# access to public folder is giving me an error

Tags: node.js

I am new to Nodejs and I am following a course on Pluralsight for Nodejs using express.
I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 5000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/books', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello Books');
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
    console.log('running server on port ' + port); 
});
```

And then from the command line I run the following:
    $ npm start

This is my json file:

```
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

Now the problem I am having is that when from my browser I put: localhost:5000 everything looks fine. I see my Hello World text. But when I am trying to go to a folder under the public such as localhost:5000/css/style.css I get the following error message.

```
Cannot GET /css/style.css
```

And here is my folder structure
[image]

Comment: Probably: *"However, the path that you provide to the `express.static` function is relative to the directory from where you launch your `node` process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve: `app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` "* https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Is the public folder next to your package.json file?

Comment: Show us what the hierarchy looks like for the `public` folder.  If you're referencing `/css/style.css`, then you need `public/css/style.css` to exist for `express.static('public')` to find it.

Comment: Make sure your file names match exactly. In this case, `style.css !== styles.css`

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I cannot believe how stupid this was. That was the problem.

Comment: Happy I was able to help! I've certainly done similar things, and worse ones as well. `camelCase !== camelcase`, `transition !== transitoin`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want:

```
localhost:5000/css/style.css
```

to be served by:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Then, you need to make sure that style.css is in:

```
public/css/style.css
```

where `public/css/style.css` is evaluated relative to the current working directory.

You don't disclose your file hierarchy, but if `localhost:5000/css/style.css` isn't working, then apparently `style.css` isn't located properly in `public/css/style.css` or your `public` directory isn't in the proper place.

`app.use(express.static('public'));` tells express to look for requested files relative to the `public` directory.  So a request for `/css/style.css` will be looked for at `public/css/style.css`.

---

Also, `app.use(express.static('public'));` assumes that the `public` directory you want it to look in is relative to the working directory when the `app.use()` statement is run so you need to either make sure that is also correct or you need to put an absolute path in the `express.static()` statement so you don't depend on the current working directory.